# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given - History and Settings classes should be well implemented?

Tags: python

I have one class I need two separate into two classes.

```
WIDTH=50
HEIGHT=10

class History(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, borderwidth=1)

        self.container = Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)

        Label(self.container, fg="white",text="History", bg='#3780ba', anchor='w', font=("Calibri", 12), width=WIDTH).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        Label(self.container, fg="white",text="Settings", bg='#3780ba', anchor='w', font= ("Calibri", 12) , width=WIDTH ).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        text_widget = Text(self.container, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH).grid(row=1, column=0)
        text_widget = Text(self.container, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH).grid(row=3, column=0)
```

This class is a bit clear. I prefer to separate into two classes. Here is my attempt :

```
class History(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.container = Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)

        Label(self.container, fg="white",text="History", bg='#3780ba', anchor='w', font=("Calibri", 12), width=WIDTH).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        Text(self.container, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH).grid(row=1, column=0)


class Settings(History):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(self, parent)

        Label(self.container, fg="white", text="Settings", bg='#3780ba', anchor='w', font= ("Calibri", 12) , width=WIDTH ).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        Text(self.container, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH).grid(row=3, column=0)
```

With

```
    self.history = History(self)
    self.history.grid(row=0, column=1)

    self.settings = Settings(self)
    self.parametres.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

I got the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 161, in <module>
    root = Game()
  File "test.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.settings = Settings(self)
  File "tests.py", line 26, in __init__
    super().__init__(self, parent)
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I am confused ... Why my classes History and Settings are not well implemented?

Comment: The `self` argument doesn't need to be passed

Comment: @IainShelvington Can you elaborate?

Comment: You need to provide a stack trace

Comment: The first line in `Settings.__init__` you call `super` and pass `self` as the first argument, you don't need to pass `self` just like you aren't doing so in `History,__init__`

Comment: Voting to close as typo since you clearly know better from the other classes.

Comment: If OP clearly knew better, I suspect the question would never have been asked - I'm usually careful about assigning attributes to people where no real knowledge exists. I also don't believe this is a typo - it's not as if people fall asleep on their keyboard and accidentally type out "self, " :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the constructor for your `Settings` class, specifically:

```
super().__init__(self, parent)
```

When you call a method of an object, the object is *implicitly* added as the first parameter to the call. That means you are effectively passing two copies of `self` and one of `parent`, resulting in the error "I wanted two but you gave me three, so go away" (paraphrased).

In other words, do not *explicitly* pass `self` (match what you do in your `History` class):

```
super().__init__(parent)
```